# Inserting a vector into a function?

Tags: function-construction, vector

Is it possible to have a $3 \times 1$ vector labeled ${\bf x}$ and a function $f$ of its components, $\{ x_1 , x_2 , x_3 \}$, where the argument of $f$ is the vector itself instead of its separate components?

Comment: Huh???   What are you asking?

Comment: If I call a function: f[x_,y_,z_] = something, can I have a 3x1 vector which I plug into the function and acts as x,y,z instead of creating three separate variables?

Comment: But you're using $x$ to represent both a three-element vector ("a 3x1 vector labeled x") *and* a component of a function.  What a mess!  Do you want `f[x_List]:= ....`?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `f[vec_List]:=Module[{x=vec[[1]],y=vec[[2]],z=vec[[3]]},
x+y+z
];` then call it like `f[{1,2,3}]`

Comment: Also not totally sure what you mean, but could you use something like [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)? Example: `f @@ {x, y, z}` gets you `f[x, y, z]`.

Comment: I am trying to have a two variable function that I can take the gradient and hession of and use it in a newton's method line search.  My problem is looping it to keep replacing the initial conditions.  If I can take a vector and input that into the function then I should just be able to set the new conditions like X=X+a*p

Comment: Boy... you are *really* confusing:  a *TWO*-variable function?  Everything you've stated is either *one* or *three*.  So you want to make a function that takes a vector and adds a scalar ($a$) times another vector?  So there are actually *three* variables ($x$, $p$, $a$)???

Comment: Sorry, I am really not trying to be.  Would it help if I linked to my original question?  I know it isn't supposed to be in an image, but I do not know how to use this site quite yet. Maybe this will help explain what and why I am trying to do what I am doing. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159884/how-to-fix-my-while-loop-no-errors-but-does-not-output-anything

Comment: I am trying to do the same and I have the same question. For instance, if I use Interpolation, I can create a function of multiple variables but it always requires f[x_,y_,z_]. I would like instad to have something like f[xv] where xv = {x,y,z}, so that I can give f[xv] instead. I can do that when I define my own functions, for instance f[xv:{__?NumberQ}]:=... I could do a Module to make this change, but this does not work because in my case what I have is something like f[x1, x2, x3, x4, ..., xn] and "n" can be any number. Maybe I can do it but it is complicated, to do it for something simple

Comment: @Sergio sorry for moving your answer but it was not a place for a question. If given answers do not address your needs, please post a new question, link this one and explain why a separate topic is needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
f1[x_List] := Total@x;

f1[{1,2,3}]
```

Also (see above):

```
f2[x_List, p_List, a_]:= x + a p;

f2[{1,2,3},{4,5,6}, .1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
f[{{x1_}, {x2_}, {x3_}}] := x1 + x2^2 + x3^3
f[Transpose[{Range[3]}]]
(* 32 *)
```

Comment: Honestly I am not sure, I put a link up top to an earlier question I posted that has an image of my code.  I am just trying to run a loop essentially. (This question was a round about way of doing that, but I think the other post makes it more clear)  `For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, 
  Subscript[X, k] = Subscript[X, k] + a*p;];` is something I've tried as well and it loops, but it doesn't set the variables to the new ones so it just keeps adding p essentially.

Comment: Avoid `Subscript`. It is a typesetting function of no mathematical significance. To create a vector use vector functions like `Table`, `Range`, etc. *Mathematica* is not C: don't use `For` unless you're an expert.